# Excessive Lagrangian intersection?

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, lagrangian-submanifolds

Assume we have a monotone Lagrangian submanifold $L$ in a 'good' symplectic manifold $X$ so that Floer homology can be defined (I am interested in $\mathbb{C}P^n$). Then $L$ and its image under Hamiltonian isotopy $\phi(L)$ intersect at at least $\mathrm{rank}\: HF(L, L)$ points (counted with multiplicity). My question is: is there any characterization of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms of $X$ giving rise to excessive intersection? Do they form a subgroup of $Ham(X)$?

The motivation is a paper of Prof. Goldstein 'Some estimates related to Oh's conjecture for the Clifford tori in $\mathbb{C}P^n$'. There, he essentially expresses the volume of a Lagrangian $L \subset \mathbb{C}P^n$ as integral of #$(L \cap\phi(L))$ over $SU(n+1)$ (acting on $\mathbb{C}P^n=SU(n+1)/U(n)$ by Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms) and gives a lower bound for #$(L \cap\phi(L))$ in terms of Floer homology. A corollary of his result is existence of a subset of non-zero measure in $SU(n+1)$ giving rise to excesssive intersection (i.e. one encounters Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms giving rise to excessive intersection generically, not on a 'locus of codimension one').

Comment: apparently, Lagrangian submanifolds for which no excessive intersection occurs have been studies in the literature previously. One might start with Y.-G. Oh's "Tight Lagrangian submanifolds in $\mathbb{C}P^n$".